# Странное поведение jQuery

Tags: jquery

Есть веб-страница, на которой естественно имеются стили и скрипты. При очистке кэша и полной перезагрузке страницы (Ctrl + F5) jQuery неправильно определяет `height()` и `width()` элемента `td` в таблице, подгруженной через AJAX, а вот при последующих обычных перезагрузках страницы (F5) всё работает как надо. В отладчике хрома ошибок нет. jQuery последней версии. Используется плагин [Tablesorter 2.0](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html)

P.S. По аналогии с `td` также плывут стили при перетаскивании элементов `sortable` из плагина jQueryUI.

Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении копать.

Comment: В настройке Tablesorter ищите ошибку.

Comment: Не думаю что дело в нём, пробовал дефолтные настройки - история идентичная. Зато обнаружилось что и у jQueryUI тоже похожий косяк возникает. Всё таки подозрения именно на jQuery

Comment: Провёл эксперимент с чистым `javascript` и вот что выдало: 
{
 javascriptHeight: 22,
 javascriptWidth: 300,
 jqueryHeight: 21,
 jqueryWidth: 293
}

а при обновлении уже:
{
 javascriptHeight: 22,
 javascriptWidth: 300,
 jqueryHeight: 22,
 jqueryWidth: 300
}

Comment: в общем заменил `height()` на `offsetHeight` и `width()` на `offsetWidth`,  полёт нормальный, но по ходу глюк всё таки где-то глубоко в jQuery надо искать

Comment: В какой момент рассчитываются размеры? Попробуй по $(window).load()

Comment: Размеры рассчитываются после загрузки через AJAX и вставки на страницу кода

Comment: Скорее всего не успевают элементы дорендериться, после обработки результата от ajax вставь расчеты размеров в обработчик $(window).load(), а не считай их сразу

Comment: Дело в том что размеры рассчитываются не автоматически а после определённого действия пользователя, в моём случае это `click` на ячейке таблицы. Таблица к тому времени уже вся загружена и отрендерена. Можно даже подождать часок другой но результат будет такой же. Самое интересное что чистый `javascript` нормально считает в том же самом месте.

Comment: Забавно, нужен пример тогда

Comment: Вот тут [https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics](https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics) хорошая статья про метрике, которая поможет лучше понять вычисление ширины и высоты элементов. А тут [http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Работа_с_высотой_элемента](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) пояснения по методам jquery. Возможно тоже поможет.

Comment: Это всё мимо, тут не метод неправильно выбран, а один и тот же метод возвращает разные значения в зависимости от момента времени

Comment: Я руководствовался комментариями автора:
— "в общем заменил height() на offsetHeight и width() на offsetWidth, полёт нормальный",
— "Таблица к тому времени уже вся загружена и отрендерена".
—  "Самое интересное что чистый javascript нормально считает в том же самом месте"

Comment: Попробую смастерить отдельный пример, из кода просто так вырвать не получится...